# How to change numbers from string to integer in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where i must take an array of strings(some numbers and some letters)and remove the Zeros, move them to the end, and return the array. The final result needs all of the numbers to be integers in the string.

I have tried mapping the array and parsing the integers. This works unless the array passed in has letters. then all the letters are relaced with NaN. I cant seem to set up a conditional that will only operate on the integers.

```
var final = ["a","b","c","d","1","1","3","1","9","9",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

but it should be

```
var final = ["a","b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I need to parse the integers but cant get map to do it without the problem i described earlier. I also tried using if statements too, with no help.

Comment: Check the conversion result, and return the original value if the result is `NaN`. You didn't post the code that's causing you problems so it's impossible to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, you may be not far from solution

Comment: @Pointy your edit may have harm the original question, you switched from a string to an array.

Comment: @Cid it wasn't a string; the OP was using back-quote characters to quote the array as code. I changed it to use block indentation instead.

Comment: In edit history, I see this : `var final = '["a","b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]'`

Comment: Yes it is suppose to be an array.Thank you for removing the backtics. The reason i didnt include my trial and error is due to the fact none of it worked. The problem is straightforward though. I need the final to look like the bottom array. And i need to know how to go about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert all numbers or try to convert and take the value, if the conversion is falsy.

```js
var final = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "1", "1", "3", "1", "9", "9", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

console.log(final.map(v => +v || v));
```

Zero safe approach.

```js
var final = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "1", "1", "3", "1", "9", "9", "0", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

console.log(final.map(v => isNaN(v) ? v : +v));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
var final = ["a","b","c","d","1","1","3","1","9","9",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

final = final.map(i => isNaN(i) ? i : Number(i));

console.log(final);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you are using json strings. Still upvoted

Comment: @cid, OP's required output is string, I just convert the array to string with `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @Cid, you are right, I didn't notice the update made in the question, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse the number but return the original element if it's NaN using a conditional:

```
var final = array.map((x) => {
    var n = parseInt(x, 10);
    return !isNaN(n) ? x : n;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```js
var input = ["0", "a", "0", "b", "0", "0", "c", "d", "0", 0, "0", "1", "0", "1","3","0", "1","9","9", "0"];

var final = [...input.filter(s => s != 0), 
             ...input.filter(s => s == 0)
            ].map(s => isNaN(s) ? s : +s);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map()` and validating on `isNaN()`.

```
["a","b","c","d","1","1","3","1","9","9",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
.map(x => !isNaN(x) ? Number(x) : x)
```